# regexp in java for indexof method

Tags: java, regex, string, indexof

Can we use regexp for indexof() method of String.
If so how

According to my knowledge this should print 1 but it
          prints "-1"

```
 System.out.println("hello".indexOf("[e]"));
```

Can some one please explain

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) there is no version of `indexof` that accepts regex. It is either a char or a String.

> `int  indexOf(int ch)`
>   Returns the index within this string of the first
>   occurrence of the specified character.
>     `int  indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`
>   Returns the index within this string of the first
>   occurrence of the specified character, starting the search at the
>   specified index.
>   `int  indexOf(String str)`
>    Returns the index within this
>   string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.
>   `int  indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)`
>    Returns the index within this
>   string of the first occurrence of the specified substring, starting at
>   the specified index.

According to this your code should be

```
System.out.println("hello".indexOf('e'));
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` simply returns the index of the first occurrence. We can simulate this behaviour with regex easily.

Example:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[e]").matcher("Hello");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.start());
}
```

You can put this into a method:

```
private static int indexOf(String s, String pattern) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        return m.start();
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```